# How do I force generated many-to-many Relation tables to the correct schema?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have tables `parkpay.User` and `parkpay.Role`. EF Code First automatically generates a third table linking the two for a many-to-many relationship, but it generates `dbo.UserRole`. How do I get it to make that table `parkpay.UserRole'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EntityTypeConfiguration<> config many-to-many mappings.

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserMapping()
    {
        ToTable("User", "parkpay");
        HasKey(e => e.Id).Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        HasMany(e => e.Roles).WithMany(e => e.Users).Map(m => m.ToTable("UserRole", "parkpay").MapLeftKey("RoleId").MapRightKey("UserId"));
    }
}

public class RoleMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public RoleMapping()
    {
        ToTable("Role", "parkpay");
        HasKey(e => e.Id).Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleMapping());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```